# Controls Collection and .Where?

Tags: vb.net, linq, iterator

Is there not a way to do the following??

```
For each ctrl as Control in Me.Controls.Where(function(x) x.Enabled = False)
    ctrl.Enabled = True
Next
```

Every which way I try, I get `'Where' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection'` presumably because `ControlCollection` is not enumerable?

Comment: The answer to how to use `Where` with ControlCollection has been given in a couple of answers. The remaining problem is that `System.Web.UI.Control` doesn't have an `Enabled` property (as the Windows Forms Control does). You will need to narrow your search to only the types of control that have an enabled property.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of figured that but is there a base type that all of those controls come from that I can just say "Enabled"? And then do so in the iterator? Without explicitly getting the type of it? Like a base class?

Comment: I added an answer that should work for most simple WebControls.

Answer (score 6):

Most LINQ extension methods extend the type-safe `IEnumerable(Of T)`.

`ControlCollection` predates generics and only implements `IEnumerable`, so the extension methods will not work.

You need to call `.Cast(Of Control)()` to return an `IEnumerable(Of Control)` which will accept extension methods.

Comment: As noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678615/controls-collection-and-where/31678713#31678713

Same thing as what you're saying but does not work.

Answer (score 3):

> because ControlCollection is not enumerable

No, because it does not implement `IEnumerable(Of T)` (historical reasons).

As you know there are only `Control` instances in the collection you can convert:

```
Me.Controls.OfType(Of Control)().Where(…
```

[`OfType(Of T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) is a method that extends `IEnumerable` to return an `IEnumerable(Of T)`.

Comment: Which gives me: Error 17 'AsType' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection'.

Comment: Thanks but it now gives an error: Error 17 'Enabled' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control

Comment: @MetalPhoenix: that's down to what you are doing with the collection. You may need to down cast from `Control` to something more specific – but without knowing which type of `Control` you have it is hard to help (WinForms, WebForms and possibly WPF all have a `Control` type).

Comment: That's kind of the point of the .Where. It's a winforms aspx page. I'm trying to get around 1. going through ALL controls and 2. Enable or disabled them regardless of type since every server control has an Enabled property. The only other solution that I have so far is to iterate the entire collection (recursively, btw) and do a select case on Typeof

Comment: @MetalPhoenix "winforms aspx page": I hope you mean "webforms" there!. You can replace the type in the `OfType` with something more specific (it both casts and filters): perhaps `WebControl`.

Comment: Ugh, yes... thanks. Multitasking. Will check later this evening and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The class only implements `IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable` but not the required `IEnumerable(Of T)` so you cannot use `Where` unless you first `Cast(Of T)` first.

Remember to `Imports System.Linq`

Then you can do the following:

```
For each ctrl as Control in Me.Controls.Cast(Of Control).Where(function(x) x.Enabled = False)
    ctrl.Enabled = True
Next
```

Note: not all controls have the `Enabled` property available, so you would instead of using `Cast(Of Control)` use `OfType()` to filter the specific controls you are after then set the enabled property.

Comment: Error 17 'enabled' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast *.Where(function ...)* on every Control, **not** on the whole ControlCollection. And you can do this only on a System.Windows.Forms.ControlCollection, not System.Web.UI.. because System.Web.Ui.Control doesn't have the property Enabled.

Try this:

```
For each ctrl as Control in Me.Controls.Cast(Of Control)
    If (Not crtl.Enabled) Then
        ctrl.Enabled = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: That code should work even without the `Cast(Of Control)` (as long as you fix the typo on the `If` statement). But the question was about being able to use the `Where` function.

Comment: This does not work. Error 17 'Enabled' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control. It doesn't know the type of control so it can't get the properties of it.

Comment: I just edited my answer: he can't use Enalbed property just because System.Web.UI doesn't have that property. Only System.Windows.Forms have it.

Comment: Controls have it but since the type of the control isn't determined and there is no "generic" list of properties - it's a property of the control, not the namespace, I can't just say ctrl.Enabled without Ctype or similar.

Comment: Where do you see that UI.Control have the Enabled property? I don't see it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control(v=vs.110).aspx
Instead System.windows.Forms.Control have it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx

Nothing left to say...

Comment: @MattMarked here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That refers another class, WebControl, not Control.. They're 2 different class from 2 different namespace.. Try casting WebControl instead of control
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As `System.Web.UI.Control` doesn't have an `Enabled` property, you need to find a class (or classes) that inherits from `Control` and that your controls all inherit from and that has an `Enabled` property. Most of the simple controls inherit from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl` which has an `Enabled` property. You can process all the controls of type `WebControl` like this.

```
For Each wCtrl As WebControls.WebControl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of WebControls.WebControl)
    wCtrl.Enabled = True
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.UI.Control not all have the Enabled property. You must verify their existence. For Framework 3.5

```
Private Function ExistPropertyEnabled(ByVal p As Reflection.PropertyInfo) As Boolean
    Return (p.Name = "Enabled")
End Function

Private Sub EnabledControls() 
    Dim evalEnabled As Predicate(Of Reflection.PropertyInfo) = AddressOf ExistPropertyEnabled

    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls.Cast(Of Control)()
        Dim ExistProperty As Boolean = Array.Exists(Of Reflection.PropertyInfo)(ctrl.GetType().GetProperties(), evalEnabled)

        If (ExistProperty AndAlso Not ctrl.Enabled) Then
            ctrl.Enabled = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```